# rcarousel scroll effect not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

using rcarousel for image gallery on my website. Everything works fine, except for scroll animation (reason for using this obviously). Inside the div are image's with link to page

[PAGE](http://www.winching-dutchmen.nl/album)

this is the script running:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                jQuery(function( $ ) {
                $( "#carousel" ).rcarousel({
                    visible: 7,
                    step: 3
                });

                $( "#carousel ").rcarousel({
                    margin: 50
                });

                $( "#ui-carousel-next" )
                    .add( "#ui-carousel-prev" )
                    .hover(
                        function() {
                            $( this ).css( "opacity", 1.0 );
                        },
                        function() {
                            $( this ).css( "opacity", 0.8 );
                        }
                    );              
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Show some code...Dont expect to inspect your site

Comment: sorry for that. posted running javascript, hope thats enough..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have missed to include `rcarousel.css`. When I included from the server, It works fine

```
http://ryrych.github.io/rcarousel/widget/css/rcarousel.css
```

Please make sure your CSS path is correct.

Comment: Thnx Sirjith. id did indeed use wronf markup for the css file, works like a charm now!